# How to get Value Member of a ComboBox by using its associated Display Text typed by user?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox which is bound to a DataSet. 
Suppose..

```
  cmbGroup.ValueMember = "Col1"
  cmbGroup.DisplayMember = "Col2"
```

I want to get the value member of the Combobox when I type in one of its Display member in it and press tab.
I have a label which gets the text of the value member `Col2`  as user changes the selected index.
But selected index does not get changed in a combobox when you type in display value into it and press tab even if the value you have typed in is a one its members . 
I will accept answer in C# as well because there are plenty of online converters available on line. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set AutoCompleteMode property to AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

Comment: TYhis is not what i need I know how to get Selected Value please read the question again

Comment: I want to change the selected Index by typing correct value in the combo box.

Comment: i understand. Have you tried what I wrote? It change SelectedIndex to to the value that has been typed by the user,

Comment: You are right by i guess i am facing problem because the datasource consists of white spaces at the end

Comment: Can you tell me how can I remove trailing whitespaces in Combobox? Although the values in database table are trimmed I am getting 2-3 whitespaces at the end of each value which is displayed in the combobox\

Comment: My mistake. Some of the values in the table were not trimmed . Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curriosity: How does this answer the question "How to get Value Member of a ComboBox by using its associated Display Text?"

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå, you right. title Should have "ComboBox.SelectedValue when user type an existing display-Value"

Comment: @lomed Yes! But if he did mean what the title says, I still think my answer is correct. If a text in the CB do not match `Col2`, checking the `cmbGroup.SelectedValue` will return a wrong value. The right value would be `Nothing`.

Answer (score -1):

Before the answer, I have to ask you please next time use better sentences :), I almost near to die to getting what you try to tell :D

You need to all members in a table added to your combo box and when user trying to type something combo box append the untyped part.

C# code for adding members in combo box:

```
        string Query = "SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName";
        using(SqlCommand comSQL = connectionDB.CreateCommand())
        {
            comSQL.CommandText = Query;
                using (SqlDataReader drSql = comSQL.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (drSQL.Read())
                    {
                        ComboBox.Items.Add(drSQL.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
        }
```

for appending untyped part you have to change the property of combo box named AutoCompleteMode:

```
ComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Append;
```

**Updated:**

For using my solution you have to unbound your combo box from DataSet.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this is so **far** away from the OP.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå in that case I really can not get it what is the question!

Comment: I don't think you're the only one;p

Comment: With that being said, he do state that the "ComboBox which is bound to a DataSet". If so, by manually modifying the `ObjectCollection` (Items) will result in an error.